# Apache ProxyPass doesn't work for nginx

Tags: apache-2.2, nginx, reverse-proxy

I'm trying to configure Apache's VirtualHost as a reverse proxy for nginx server (all of the current apps are using Apache and this new app is using some specific features of nginx). Used configuration:

```
<VirtualHost ***.***.***.***:80>
    ServerAdmin ****
    ServerName ****

    ProxyRequests Off
    <Proxy *>
        Order deny,allow
        Allow from all
    </Proxy>

    ProxyPass / http://localhost:8071/
    ProxyPassReverse / http://localhost:8071/
    <Location />
        Order allow,deny
        Allow from all
    </Location>
</VirtualHost>
```

with nginx/uwsgi running on port 8071 (tried curl it on server and it worked). However, Apache still refuses to route requests to nginx. Is there some specific setting I need to change or some other file to edit?

Comment: This seems a bit backwards. Way Apache at all?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answer to this was really pretty simple, owners of the domain didn't set it to a new IP address. So if you ever encouter this problem, consider running `dig <your-URL>` command.